# Matching ISO2C country codes with country names in R with countrycode

Tags: r

I am a complete beginner in R, working on my first dataset. In this dataset, I have a column with country codes (the column name is "country") and I would like to transform the codes into full country names. I found a great thread on stackoverflow explaining the countrycode package, however my code doesn't work as expected, I am getting an error: **Incomplete expression: ufo%>% mutate(country = myCodes(country, "iso2c", "country.name")**

How do I properly mutate the country column to convert the codes into country names?

```
ufo <- ufo%>% 
  separate(datetime, c("date", "time"), sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(country = as.factor(country),
         shape = as.factor(shape),
         date = as.factor(date)) %>%
  mutate(date=as.Date(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y", origin = "1970-01-01"))
myCodes <- c("au", "ca", "de", "gb", "us")
countrycode(myCodes, "iso2c", "country.name")
ufo%>% mutate(country = myCodes(country, "iso2c", "country.name")
```

Comment: Can you provide a dataset or at least a few rows?

Comment: I think the problem is in wrong name of the function. It should be countrycode instead of MyCodes. : `ufo%>% mutate(country = countrycode(country, "iso2c", "country.name"))`  You are also missing one `)` at the end of your expression.

Comment: @Bloxx Thank you! I am using scrubbed.csv from here: https://www.kaggle.com/NUFORC/ufo-sightings

I reworked the code, but now I am getting a column with NAs instead of country names, do you know what could be the issue?

`countrycode(ufo$country, "iso2c", "country.name")
ufo%>%
  mutate(country = countrycode(country, "iso2c", "country.name"))`

Comment: @Bloxx, problem solved! The ISO2C codes had to be converted to uppercase first. Thank you for your help!

Comment: As the code currently stands it still exhibits the incomplete expression error.